# "Namespace 'TagsEditText' is not bound" pero al sustituirlo por app todo es correcto

Tags: android, xml, layout

Utilizando la siguiente librería, https://github.com/mabbas007/TagsEditText sigo los pasos 1, 2 y 3 que indica el desarrollador pero en el `layout` recibo el siguiente error:

```
"Namespace 'TagsEditText' is not bound"
```

El código escrito es el mismo indicado en el paso 3:

```
<mabbas007.tagsedittext.TagsEditText
        android:id="@+id/tagsEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        TagsEditText:allowSpaceInTag="true"
        TagsEditText:tagsCloseImageRight="@drawable/tag_close"
        TagsEditText:tagsBackground="@drawable/square"
        TagsEditText:tagsCloseImageLeft="@drawable/dot"
        TagsEditText:tagsTextColor="@color/blackOlive"
        TagsEditText:tagsTextSize="@dimen/defaultTagsTextSize"
        TagsEditText:tagsCloseImagePadding="@dimen/defaultTagsCloseImagePadding"/>
```

Así queda el código funcionando correctamente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="gastuak.nire.aldakur.net.niregastuak.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">



    <mabbas007.tagsedittext.TagsEditText
            android:id="@+id/tagsEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:allowSpaceInTag="true"
            app:tagsCloseImageRight="@drawable/tag_close"
            app:tagsBackground="@drawable/square"
            app:tagsCloseImageLeft="@drawable/dot"
            app:tagsTextColor="@color/blackOlive"
            app:tagsTextSize="@dimen/defaultTagsTextSize"
    app:tagsCloseImagePadding="@dimen/defaultTagsCloseImagePadding"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Sustituyendo `TagsEditText`por `app:` el error desaparece y la app funciona correctamente. Me gustaría saber la razón de esto.

Comment: Utilizando `TagsEditText`recibo el error comentado `"Namespace 'TagsEditText' is not bound"`

Comment: Mi proyecto de Android no se llama ni `TagsEditText` ni `app`. Tiene otro nombre. Lo que estoy haciendo es utilizar la librería de un tercero. Exactamente esta: https://github.com/mabbas007/TagsEditText

Comment: He editado la pregunta con el último código completo.

Comment: Usa el correcto namespace: que es xmlns:TagsEditText="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto en el código puedes encontrar varios ejemplos al usar la clase: mabbas007.tagsedittext.TagsEditText agregue una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón es que en el ejemplo se utilizó otro namespace para http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto

En lugar de usar `app` que es lo usual, utiliza `TagsEditText` como namespace [ver](https://github.com/mabbas007/TagsEditText/blob/master/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml#L3)

El xmlns puede tener el nombre que uno quiera, pero luego se debe hacer referencia al que definiste, pudiendo ser:

`xmlns:TagsEditText="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
`xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`
`xmlns:ejemplo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

Esto se puede ver revisando el código de [TagsEditText](https://github.com/mabbas007/TagsEditText/tree/5147a5eef0e935e25374af2b78aacbcd970ba2b9) en el layout [activity_main.xml](https://github.com/mabbas007/TagsEditText/blob/5147a5eef0e935e25374af2b78aacbcd970ba2b9/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml):

```
xmlns:TagsEditText="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Answer (score 1):

Este error

> "Namespace '...' is not bound"

**Sucede por no usar el correcto namespace definido por la clase usada.**

Si revisas el código de **[TagsEditText](https://github.com/mabbas007/TagsEditText/tree/5147a5eef0e935e25374af2b78aacbcd970ba2b9)**, puedes ver cual es el correcto:

```
 xmlns:TagsEditText="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

por ejemplo en el layout [**activity_main.xml**](https://github.com/mabbas007/TagsEditText/blob/5147a5eef0e935e25374af2b78aacbcd970ba2b9/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml)

Comment: no es necesario definirlo como TagsEditText, el namespace es una referencia a "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: Y eliminar `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`?

Comment: @aldakur para TagsEditText necesitas xmlns:TagsEditText="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" pero probablemente tienes otro elemento que usa  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: Sí. Por eso es correcto tener las dos lineas? aunque las dos apunten a la misma URL?